# DOMContentLoaded on DOM <object> doesn't work in Edge

Tags: javascript, object, domcontentloaded

To get the DOMContentLoaded event of an included object like this

```
<object class="emb" data="./probe-object.html" width="100" height="100" type="text/html">
```

works in Chrome and Firefox with the following code, but not Edge.

```
let includedObject = document.querySelector(".emb object");
includedObject.contentWindow.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    includeObject();
});
```

How can I do something similar in Edge?

Comment: Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: IE doesn't support ES6 fully.

Comment: The used browser is Edge, it is a bit more different browser. :P

Comment: The problem is that contentWindow is empty: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: This is Microsoft Edge 41.16299.492.0 and Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299. maybe it is solved in later version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
   includedObject.contentWindow.addEventListener
```

is replaced with

```
   includedObject.contentDocument.addEventListener
```

it works in Edge, but not in Edge nor Firefox. This seems like an Edge bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code like this:

```
let includedObject = document.querySelector("object.emb");
includedObject.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    includeObject();
});
```

Check you console. I guess you find usefull error about this.

The selector was not correct, so I guess, it generate an undefined contentWindow error. This contentWindow used for iframe objects and you has only an object tag.

Comment: includedObject gets content in my original call. With your call it becomes empty.

Comment: What object is in the "./probe-object.html" ? There is another <object> in this html?